# Python (int) error

Tags: python

```
import random

    numbers = int(input("Please, enter number {}: ".format(i+1)) for i in range(7))

# will display prompt like "Please, enter number 1:"
    print ("numbers entered:"), numbers # this will print the entered numbers

    positives = [num for num in numbers if num > 0]
    negatives = [num for num in numbers if num < 0]

# loop ends here
    print ("Sum of negative numbers is :", sum(negatives))
    print ("Average negative number is :", sum(negatives)*1.0/len(negatives))
    print ("Sum of positive numbers is :", sum(positives))
    print ("Average positive number is :", sum(positives)*1.0/len(positives))
```

my issue is that when i run in idle i get the following error:
 "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator"
not sure how to fix this... i know that when using python 3 i have to use (int) before input to call on an integer but am unsure how to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, `int` does not support generator expressions.  However, you try to give it one here:

```
numbers = int(input("Please, enter number {}: ".format(i+1)) for i in range(7))
```

The above code is equivalent to this:

```
numbers = int(
              # This is a generator expression
              input("Please, enter number {}: ".format(i+1)) for i in range(7)
          )
```

---

What I think you are trying to do is this:

```
numbers = [int(input("Please, enter number {}: ".format(i+1))) for i in range(7)]
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> numbers = [int(input("Please, enter number {}: ".format(i+1))) for i in range(7)]
Please, enter number 1: 1
Please, enter number 2: 2
Please, enter number 3: 3
Please, enter number 4: 4
Please, enter number 5: 5
Please, enter number 6: 6
Please, enter number 7: 7
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```

Comment: Why would you encourage somebody that's obviously just learning the language to write something like that?

Comment: @SeanMcSomething - I don't think this is too advanced for him--he himself is using list comprehensions in his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

numbers = []
for i in range(7):
    numbers.append(int(input("Please, enter number {}: ".format(i+1))))

# will display prompt like "Please, enter number 1:"
print ("numbers entered:"), numbers # this will print the entered numbers

positives = [num for num in numbers if num > 0]
negatives = [num for num in numbers if num < 0]

# loop ends here
if len(negatives) > 0:
    print ("Sum of negative numbers is :", sum(negatives))
    print ("Average negative number is :", sum(negatives)*1.0/len(negatives))
if len(positives) > 0:
    print ("Sum of positive numbers is :", sum(positives))
    print ("Average positive number is :", sum(positives)*1.0/len(positives))
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means exactly what it says - `int()` only takes strings or objects and you're trying to call int on a generator expression.  Stripping it down to something a bit simpler, you're saying `int( f(x) for x in range(7) )` which makes about as much sense as saying `int( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] )`.  Python won't magically apply functions across lists (or generators or iterators or...).

While you could simply toss this into a list comprehension by adding a few characters (as other posters have suggested), the nature of this problem suggests you're just learning Python.  Writing ugly, convoluted expressions is a bad habit to get into and makes code hard to read/maintain/expand.  You should probably use an actual loop for the sake of readability.

```
numbers = []
for i in range(7):
    prompt = "Please, enter number {}: ".format(i+1)
    user_input = input(prompt)
    user_num = int(user_input)
    numbers.append(user_num)
```

It takes up a few more lines but it's easier to follow or modify.  Let's say you wanted to remove the limit on how many numbers to input or disallow prime numbers - do you think you'd be able to do that easily with the original version?